# Setting up a Proxy QScriptEngineAgent for script monitoring

Tags: c++, qt, proxy, qtscript

I am using the QScriptEngine and QScriptEngineDebugger and I was reading the documentation of the QScriptEngine and I saw the following:

> “**void QScriptEngineDebugger::attachTo ( QScriptEngine * engine )**
>   Attaches to the given engine. The debugger will install a custom agent
>   (using QScriptEngine::setAgent()) to monitor the engine. While the
>   debugger is attached, you should not change the agent; however, if you
>   do have to perform additional monitoring, you must set a proxy agent
>   that forwards all events to the debugger’s agent.”

So what I would like to do is actually monitor the execution of my Script using the Debugger but I would like more information.

Is there any example available for this topic? I couldn’t find any example of the so call “proxy agent” and I don’t know how to start/set it.

Thanks in advance any kind of help is welcome :O

Comment: There's also an option to automatically start the debugger if your script throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `debugger.standardWindow()->show()` to show the debugger's GUI:

```
QScriptEngine engine;
QScriptEngineDebugger debugger;
debugger.attachTo(&engine);
debugger.standardWindow()->show();
engine.evaluate(QScriptProgram("a = 0; \nb = 0; \nc = a + d;"));
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your response. I can succesfully attach a Debugger to my ScriptEngine, the thing is when I try to debug a script and get to a function defined inside an imported extension I only get the line number and not the script text being evaluated. So that's why I am focusing on the Custom QScriptAgent set by the QScriptDebugger to get the script text that is omitted.